# Error 302 Using FeignClient in Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I have a problem with FeignClient. I am deployed Spring Boot applications, I get an error in a call to a specific feign client, the error comes up when I use a registration microservice when wanting to communicate with a specific method of a user microservice, with other methods the problem does not occur, I also have a Eureka server for discovery and a gateway with Spring Cloud Gateway, configured with the configuration for permissions. I have @EnableEurekaClient and @EnableFeignClients in applications and they can be seen on the Eureka server, and implements CircuitBreaker with resilience4j.
For testing I use postman.

for a request:

[image: postman request]

Without CircuitBreaker I get this error

```
feign.FeignException: [302] during [GET] to [http://app-usuarios/users/usuarioExisteDatos/?username=admin&email=admin%40udea.edu.co&cellPhone=3128211358] [UsersFeignClient#preguntarUsuarioExiste(String,String,String)]: true
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:182) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
at jdk.proxy11/jdk.proxy11.$Proxy250.preguntarUsuarioExiste(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.app.registro.controllers.RegistroController.crearNuevo(RegistroController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

With CircuitBreaker:

```
[302] during [GET] to [http://app-usuarios/users/usuarioExisteDatos/?username=admin&email=admin%40udea.edu.co&cellPhone=3128211358] [UsersFeignClient#preguntarUsuarioExiste(String,String,String)]: [true]
```

for my registro microservice:

Model:

```
@Document(collection = "registro")
public class Registro {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be null")
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+", message = "Solo se permite:'_' o '.' o '-'")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[^ ]*+", message = "Caracter: ' ' (Espacio en blanco) invalido")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "About Me must be between 6 and 20 characters")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Cell phone cannot be null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "Solo numeros")
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String cellPhone;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be null")
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[^ ]*+", message = "Caracter: ' ' (Espacio en blanco) invalido")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String codigo;
    private List<String> roles;

    ** Constructors, setters and getters
}
```

My Client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "app-usuarios")
public interface UsersFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/users/usuarioExisteDatos")
    public Boolean preguntarUsuarioExiste(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "cellPhone") String cellPhone);
    
    @GetMapping("/users/listar")
    public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios();
}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
public class RegistroController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistroController.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Autowired
    private CircuitBreakerFactory cbFactory;

    @Autowired
    UsersFeignClient uClient;

    @GetMapping("/registro/listarUsuarios")
    public List<Usuario> verUsuarios() {
        return uClient.listarUsuarios();
    }

    @PostMapping("/registro/crearNuevo")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Boolean crearNuevo(@RequestBody @Validated Registro registro) {
        // return uClient.preguntarUsuarioExiste(registro.getUsername(),
        // registro.getEmail(), registro.getCellPhone());
        return (Boolean) cbFactory.create("usuarios").run(() -> uClient.preguntarUsuarioExiste(registro.getUsername(),
                registro.getEmail(), registro.getCellPhone()), e -> preguntarUsuarioExiste2(registro.getUsername(), e));
    }

    private Object preguntarUsuarioExiste2(String username, Throwable e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
```

my application properties:

```
#-------APP-------
spring.application.name=app-registro
server.port=${PORT:0}

#-----MongoDb------
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=user
spring.data.mongodb.database=usuariosApp
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true

#-----Eureka-------
eureka.instance.metadataMap.instanceId=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#-----Feign-------
feign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=10000
feign.client.config.default.read-timeout=10000
feign.client.config.default.logger-level=full
```

My Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app.registro</groupId>
    <artifactId>App-Registro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>App-Registro</name>
    <description>Registro for App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My method in microservice usuarios:

```
@GetMapping("/users/usuarioExisteDatos")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public Boolean preguntarUsuarioExiste(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "cellPhone") String cellPhone)
            throws InterruptedException {
        return uRepository.existsByUsernameOrEmailOrCellPhone(username, email, cellPhone);
    }
```

It should be noted that you are making a call to a MongoRepository interface

If I call the other client method, listUsers, the feign client works fine:

[image: Users List]

My method in microservicie usuarios for this is:

```
@GetMapping("/users/listar")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios() {
        return uRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I don't understand why this happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here but let me clarify why this happens. Feign is an HTTP binder for your APIs. In normal cases when you communicate backend-backend, the de-facto accepted HTTP status codes are `2xx` to indicate that everything worked as expected. When an API reponds with a `3xx` (`302` in your case), that indicates a redirect which is usually used to instruct the browser to redirect the user to another page upon doing something.

Anyway, now that we've cleared why this could happen, let's see why your Feign client behaves this way. All Feign clients have a configuration parameter called `follow-redirects`. This controls whether upon receiving a `3xx` HTTP response, the Feign client should automatically try to call the API specified in the response's `Location` header.

By default this parameter is set to true, meaning that redirects will be followed and it will be transparent for you, as a client user. From the exception, I think you somehow disabled it or you might use an HTTP client for which you disabled the redirect following manually.

Although I can clearly see from your implementation in the `preguntarUsuarioExiste` method that you're trying to decide whether a user exists in the system or not. In this case the `302 HTTP Found` status doesn't make sense even though I understand why you'd want to use that (cause the term reflects that the user exists).

In this case, I'd simply remove the fixed `302` status with the `@ResponseStatus` annotation and change the API to return a `ResponseEntity` instead to resolve the status code dynamically. Something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users/usuarioExisteDatos")
public ResponseEntity<?> preguntarUsuarioExiste(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username, @RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "cellPhone") String cellPhone) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean exists = uRepository.existsByUsernameOrEmailOrCellPhone(username, email, cellPhone);
    if (exists) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

This way when you invoke the API from the Feign client, you can simply handle the 404 case as a user is not found. Or even better, you could simply create an object as a response for your API which has the boolean value whether or not the user exists, something like:

```
{
  "exists": false
}
```

Then you can map this object in your Feign client and deal with pure booleans.

As last, if you want to stick with the 302 status code, you can change your Feign client definition to return a `feign.Response` class instead of a `Boolean`.

That way, it will not fail with an exception but you'll be in full control of what should happen with the response. You can access the status code, the body, everything what you need.

I strongly suggest to learn a bit more about Feign, there are many more culprits you can fall into especially when you're combining it with service resiliency tools like Eureka and Resilience4J. And I'm not trying to advertise here but I really believe you need some guidance.

Check out my blog for articles on Feign: [arnoldgalovics.com Feign articles](https://arnoldgalovics.com/tag/feign/)

And also, check out my course for Feign, Spring Cloud OpenFeign and Resilience4J integration. I'm pretty much covering all what you'll need: [Mastering microservice communication with Spring Cloud Feign](https://www.udemy.com/course/mastering-microservice-communication-with-spring-cloud-feign/?referralCode=437693FE520ABDF6F4E3)